# using GPO to prevent WSUS/Windows Update from applying updates to our Servers

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, wsus

We want to prevent our servers from rebooting after an update is automatically applied, as this has happened in the past and one server sat on a "press F1 to continue" screen.

I think if we create an OU that has our server computers, and apply a GPO to that OU, we can prevent the servers from taking updates and also prevent rebooting. Please advise.

Comment: You still should fix why the server needed F1 to continue.

Comment: This is all readily available in documentation, is google broken?

Comment: Are you already using WSUS?  Have you already reviewed the Microsoft Support article [How to configure automatic updates by using Group Policy or registry settings](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/328010)?

Comment: thanks Xeon, yes we fixed the f1 error. I've made a note to fix that fresh out of the box going forward for new systems we receive ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put both servers in an OU and apply a GPO to that OU that prevents automatic installation of updates (and the subsequent reboot) or, alternatively, you can leave the servers where they are in the AD, create a security group and make the server computers members, then apply a GPO at the root of the domain filtered by the security group you created such that only the members of that group can apply the policy.

Either way will work. I generally have all my server computers below a single OU (with the exception of Domain Controller computers) and just have a "Member Servers and Domain Controllers" GPO that includes this kind of setting linked at both the "Domain Controllers" OU and the top-level OU of the hierarchy of OUs that contain the member server computers. (I almost never allow server computers to apply updates and reboot on their own.)

Comment: Thanks Evan for clarrifying for me which is better to use. I was confused on which option to take, the security group or the OU. I've applied a GPO at the OU level. I've moved our computers into two OUs: Computers - Workstations; Computers - Servers . Now we have a seperate WSUS GPO targetting each differently.